# awk or sed command to average and peak value

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to calculate the average and peak of the 3rd column within one hour (Mentioned in 2nd column). Please help to resolve.

```
27022019    2:00:01   3 
27022019    2:05:01   14
27022019    2:10:01   12
27022019    2:15:01   22
27022019    2:20:01   12
27022019    2:25:01   13
27022019    2:30:01   13
27022019    2:35:02   13
27022019    2:40:01   13
27022019    2:45:01   12
27022019    2:50:01   13
27022019    2:55:01   12
```

Based on the one input, I am successful to calculate avg and peak for one hour(between 2-3Hrs as given in 2nd column).

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^02:/' test.txt \
  | awk '{sum+=$3;max=(max>$3?max:$3)} 
         END{print "Between Hrs 2-3" " " "avg="sum/FNR " " "Max="max}' 
Between Hrs 2-3 avg=12.6667 Max=22
```

But When I am putting same in for loop, it is giving error as below:

```
for i in 02: 
do 
awk '$2 ~ /^$i/' test.txt | awk '{sum+=$3;max=(max>$3?max:$3)} END{print "Between Hrs 2-3" " " "avg="sum/FNR " " "Max="max}'
done 
awk: 0602-566 Cannot divide by zero. 
The source line number is 1.
```

Comment: within one hour... how do you define it?  2:00-3:00 or one hour till NOW?

Comment: Dear Spot, don't be alarmed that your question is closed. It just implies that we are unsure of what you are asking and you need to be a bit more specific. We are missing the following information: (1) What do you mean with one-hour intervals (cfr comment Kent) and (2) what did you try and what are the issues you have. Please update your question so we can help you out. Also take the time to take the [tour] and have a look at [ask].

Comment: [in case this is reopened:] _average and peak of 3rd column within one hour (Mentioned in 2nd column)_ So the 1st field date won't have any affect?

Comment: Hi, Need to calculate the avg and peak for 3rd column between 2:00:01 and 2:55:01 in 2nd column. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should add the desired output, and maybe show what the result of your efforts was so we can help fix them. Don't forget to indent code with four spaces, they have been edited in by others a few times now.

Comment: Based on the one input, I am successful to calculate avg and peak for one hour(between 2-3Hrs as given in 2nd column).       awk '$2 ~ /^02:/' test.txt | awk '{sum+=$3;max=(max>$3?max:$3)} END{print "Between Hrs 2-3" " " "avg="sum/FNR " " "Max="max}'
Between Hrs 2-3 avg=12.6667 Max=22
        But When I am putting same in for loop, it is giving error as below:      for i in 02:
> do
> awk '$2 ~ /^$i/' test.txt | awk '{sum+=$3;max=(max>$3?max:$3)} END{print "Between Hrs 2-3" " " "avg="sum/FNR " " "Max="max}'
> done
awk: 0602-566 Cannot divide by zero.
 The source line number is 1.

Comment: Spot, in your example input, do you have a zero in front of the hours (`02:00:01` vs currently printed `2:00:01`)

Answer (score 0):

`$2 ~ /^$i/` is never true and so that first awk command cannot be producing any output and so your 2nd script will always have FNR of 0 in its END section, hence the divide by zero error.

To the various ways to access the value of a shell variable within an awk script see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 but in your code you could do:

```
awk -v i="$i" '$2 ~ ("^"i)'`
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Then how to pass this variable ($i) in awk command?  (awk  '$2 ~ /^$i/' test.txt)

Comment: @spot passing variable to awk is via  (one way) the `-v` argument `awk -v AwkVar=Content 'BEGIN{print "My var is:" AwkVar }'`. If content is not a number, encapsulate between quote (single or double)

Comment: @spot I added an example, but depending on what it is you're really trying to do you'd probably be far better just doing everything in one call to awk rather than a shell loop calling awk multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS="( +|:)"
}
{                                           # $2==2 {  # to limit to an hour
    s[$2]+=$NF                              # sum the values
    c[$2]++                                 # count the values
    p[$2]=(p[$2]==""||p[$2]<$NF?$NF:p[$2])  # get peak val
}
END {
    for(i in s)                             # for all entries
        print i,s[i]/c[i],p[i]              # print hour, average and peak
}' file
```

Output:

```
2 12.4167 22
```